# NGINX strict redirect without query parameters

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a URL:

```
https://www.example.com/test.html
```

This URL can have query parameters like:

```
https://www.example.com/test.html?cat=11&rating=5
```

I want to redirect ONLY:

```
https://www.example.com/test.html
```

To:

```
https://www.example.com/test2
```

When I do so via:

```
location = /test.html {
    return 301 https://example.com/test2;
}
```

The URL with parameters also redirects:
https://www.example.com/test.html?cat=11&rating=5

redirects to: https://example.com/test2

Is it possible to redirect URL strictly without the affecting parameters?

UPDATE: I still want https://www.example.com/test.html?cat=11&rating=5 to work as normal, but the https://www.example.com/test.html should do the redirect to /test2

UPDATE: my local docker machine server section of NGINX

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name magento.test;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/php;

    set $maintenance off;

    if (-f $MAGE_ROOT/maintenance.enable){
        set $maintenance on;
    }

    include /var/www/php/nginx.conf;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
root $MAGE_ROOT;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";
add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff';    

# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}


# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=4000M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }    

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=4000M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query arguments are not subject to test in `location` or `rewrite` directives, they works only with the normalized URI of HTTP request. The only way to do what you want is to check [`$args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) (or [`$is_args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args)) variable:

```
location = /test.html {
    if ($is_args = '') {
        return 301 /test2;
    }
    ... # default request processing
}
```

If you show your full `server` block, maybe I could suggest more optimized solution. For example, if you have only one `location` block, something like this should work:

```
location / {
    if ($is_args = '') {
        rewrite ^/test\.html$ /test2 permanent;
    }
    ... # default request processing
}
```

However there can be a caveat with this configuration. I don't know if the various browsers takes into account query string while caching redirects, and it could lead to unconditional redirect with any request to `/test.html` no matter of query string presence. To avoid it I suggest to use 302 temporary redirect:

```
return 302 /test2;
```

or

```
rewrite ^/test\.html$ /test2 redirect;
```

**Update**

You can either add this check to `server` context in the main configuration file:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name magento.test;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/php;

    set $maintenance off;

    if (-f $MAGE_ROOT/maintenance.enable){
        set $maintenance on;
    }

    if ($is_args = '') {
        rewrite ^/test\.html$ /test2 permanent;
    }

    include /var/www/php/nginx.conf;
}
```

or to `location / { ... }` block of magento configuration file:

```
location / {
    if ($is_args = '') {
        rewrite ^/test\.html$ /test2 permanent;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: I'm working with Magento 2. The URL parameters are handled by a plugin. I just want to overwrite one of the categories to a static page. 

Your solution works, but I don't know how to passthrough the redirection to the plugin. Is there a way to let redirection pass through after the if statement? So if your if statement does not trigger, just let the redirection be handled by the plugin?

Comment: I tried something like this: location /hardware.html {if ($is_args = '') {rewrite ^/hardware\.html$ /test-page permanent;}}. The IF statement works. But when I add location /hardware.html {if ($is_args = '') {rewrite ^/hardware\.html$ /test-page permanent;}return 301 /hardware.html$args;} it still redirects to test-page.

Comment: @KalvinKlien 1. `$args` variable value doesn't include a question sign, right directive is `return 301 /hardware.html?$args;`. 2. Are you sure this isn't a cached result? Can you check an actual server response with something like `curl` from command line? Anyway I'm going to check this on my sandbox, I will tell you what I got after testing this.

Comment: I dont really have any caching set up. This is all on my docker local machine.I have tried your suggestion: location /hardware.html {if ($is_args = '') {rewrite ^/hardware\.html$ /test-page permanent;}return 301 /hardware.html?$args;} and this just shows multiple redirect error. I tried couple of browsers.

Comment: @KalvinKlien Oh, of course you got an infinite loop with this config since you are redirecting `/hardware.html?some_query_string` to itself. And I mean caching inside browser (they caches 301 redirects like any other static content), not nginx caching. You need to process this `/hardware.html` request like any other requests, but I need to see your whole `server` block to suggest how to do it.

Comment: I added the server section.

Comment: I'm also confused by NGINX regex - \/hardware.html$ - this line should have stopped at .html. $ should constitute end of line. This should not be letting ? parameters through.

Comment: @KalvinKlien Once again - both `location` and `rewrite` directives works with the normalized URI of HTTP request, not the whole request string. You can't check query string with `location` or `rewrite` directives, normalized URI does not contain that string, it contains only `/hardware.html` in your case no matter if query string is present or not. You don't need to shield `/` symbol in nginx regexes (though you can do it if you want to), but if you don't shield a dot symbol, it would match any character.

Comment: @KalvinKlien I need to see your `location` blocks, this one gave me nothing. Probably they are inside the `/var/www/php/nginx.conf`? Look at my second example, I'm using `location / { ... }`, not the `/location = test.html { ... }`. That's because I want to process any other request default way including `/hardware.html` with query arguments.

Comment: @KalvinKlien You can try `if ($is_args = '') { rewrite ^/hardware\.html$ /test-page permanent; }` directly in `server` context outside of any `location` blocks, add this before the `include /var/www/php/nginx.conf;` line.

Comment: Added the location sections. This is just standard Magento 2 nginx.conf file.

Comment: Yes this worked! if ($is_args = '') { rewrite ^/hardware\.html$ /test-page permanent; }. Ok now just server implementation left! Thanks! Please add this to your answer and I'll accept as correct answer!